# NgCSV not generating data for CSV file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, object

So I have an app that is supposed to POST to an API and then I take that response, generate the links from it, and export it to a CSV file that looks like this.

[image]

I do that by the following function here.

```
scope.exportWidget = function () {


            var query2 = QueryService.getQuery();
            query2.query.start = 0;
            query2.query.count = 20;
            query2.query.sortBy = 'date';
            query2.query.sortOrder = 'desc';
            delete (query2.query.temporal);
            delete (query2.query.geospatial);
            query2.count = 20;
            query2.start = 0;


            DataService.exportTable(query2).then(function (res) {
                var data = angular.fromJson(CSV2JSON(res.data));
                angular.forEach(data, function (obj, prop) {
                    obj.Link = DataService.buildLink(obj.Link);
                });
                console.log(data);
                scope.data = data;
                return data;
                var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
                /*anchor.attr({
                    href: 'data:attachment/csv;chartset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(res.data),
                    target: "_blank",
                    download: 'events.csv'
                })[0].click();*/
            });


        };
```

Which is tied to the following piece of HTML:

```
<span ng-csv="exportWidget()" csv-header="['Date', 'Data Source', 'CCMD', 'Country', 'Province', 'IED Type', 'Incident Type', 'Title', 'Link' ]" filename="events.csv" ng-show="item.settings.widgetType ==='table'" class="widget-controls" title="Export"><i class="fa icon-export-file"></i></span>
```

However when I click on the button that handles the exporting, my CSV file looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure exactly how to make it so that the CSV File actually is populate with the correct data.

What the scope.data array looks like is this (an array of objects):
[image]

Comment: You're missing a `return` for the `exportWidget()` function. Use `return DataService.exportTable(query2).then(...`

Comment: So the return data line in the DataService.exportTable(query2).then(... is in the wrong place?

Comment: No, you need both. The outer one I'm suggesting returns the promise. You still need the inner one to return the correct value for promise resolution